# If $D_1 f$ exists and is bounded, and $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that the map $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous. Moreover, assume that the partial derivative in the first coordinate, $D_1 f$, exists and is bounded. I'm trying to show that $f$ must be continuous.

---

What I have so far:

The condition that $D_1f$ exists and is bounded is equivalent to saying that for all $(a_1,a_2) \in U$, $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} (f(a_1+t,a_2)-f(a_1,a_2))$$ exists and is bounded.

The condition that $y \to f(x,y)$ is continuous is equivalent to $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0)$$ but I can't really see a sensible way of linking these together straight away. (I know the $D_1f$ condition must be important because it's not necessarily true that $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ and $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ both being componentwise continuous implies $f$ continuous). How do you go about showing the result?

Comment: Maybe from the boundedness of the partial derivative you can use a Lipschitz argument to show that x to f is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

I misread first and thought the result is false. It is **true.** Here is a *hint.*

Write
$$
f(x+h,y+k) - f(x,y) = f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y+k)+f(x,y+k)-f(x,y).
$$
By the mean value theorem, $|f(x+h, y+k) - f(x,y+k)| \leq c|h|$ where $c$ bounds $D_1f.$ and by continuity $f(x,y+k)-f(x,y) \to 0$ as $k \to 0.$ The result should follow easily.

Comment: You should probably mention the justification of continuity needed to apply the mean value theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin the mean value theorem $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq c|x-y|$ does not require $f$ to be continuously differentiable.

Comment: No, of course not; in our situation, it requires $f(\cdot,y)$ to be continuous.

Comment: If a function is differentiable, it is continuous. So the existence of $D_1f$ guarantees the continuity of the partial functions of $x$ alone.